# Manter informações do while em variável

Tags: php, html, mysql, while

Tenho um código onde possui um `while` dentro de outro, para poder listar produtos dentro do carrinho de compras dividido por lojas. Logo, ao ver listado os produtos, como na imagem 1. [image: imagem 1]

Como na foto acima, o meu problema é o seguinte ao clicar em comprar eu precisaria ter o *id* da loja que estou finalizando a compra, só que como fiz essa exibição com while ele sempre salva o ultimo *id* processado no `while`... vou colocar o código, teria como eu fazer com que ao clicar em comprar ele abrisse o numero respectivo a loja?

```
while ($linhaaa = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadooo)) {

                        //cria variavel com o numero da loja    
                        $codigo_loja = $linhaaa["cod_loja"];
                        //seleciona tudo de compra com join de produtos_clientes com cod_user - essa parte vai exibir os produtos
                        $sintaxesql = "SELECT compra.cod_compra, compra.cod_user, compra.item, compra.tipo_entrega, compra.cod_loja, produtos_clientes.cod_colar, 
                        produtos_clientes.nome, produtos_clientes.preco, produtos_clientes.id_cliente, produtos_clientes.modalidade, produtos_clientes.cod_loja
                        FROM compra
                        JOIN produtos_clientes
                        ON compra.item = produtos_clientes.cod_colar && produtos_clientes.cod_loja = compra.cod_loja WHERE compra.cod_user='$cod_user' && compra.cod_loja='$codigo_loja'";
                        $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sintaxesql);
                        //define a variavel de soma dos produtos
                        $total_pedido_soma = 0;
                        //abre while pra mostrar os itens que ele possui no carrinho                           
                        echo '<table class = "table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope = "col">Ações</th>
                                <th scope = "col">Nome do Vendedor</th>
                                <th scope = "col">Item</th>
                                <th scope = "col">Nome</th>
                                <th scope = "col">Preço</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>';
                        while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                            //calcula o total do pedido
                            $total_pedido_soma =
                            $total_pedido_soma = $total_pedido_soma + $linha["preco"];
                            //trata a exibição para monetária somente a linha não o resultado final
                            $linha["preco"] = str_replace(".", ",", $linha["preco"]);
                            //verifica o tipo de entrega
                            $tipo_entrega = $linha["tipo_entrega"];
                            //query para buscar nome do vendedor
                            $id_cliente = $linha["id_cliente"];
                            $sintaxesqll = "SELECT nome FROM usuario WHERE cod_user='$id_cliente'";
                            $resultadoo = mysqli_query($link, $sintaxesqll);
                            $linhaa = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoo);
                            //exibe conforme o tipo de entrega                                                               
                            echo'<tbody><td>';
                            echo '    <a href="/controller/edita_colar_carrinho.php?cod=' . $linha["item"] . '&cod_funcao=2"><img class="si-glyph-pencil" id="borda" src="svg/svg/icons8-delete.png"/></a>

                                      ';
                            echo'</td>
                                <td>' . $linhaa["nome"] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $linha["item"] . '</td>
                                <td>' . $linha["nome"] . '</td>
                                <td>R$: ' . $linha["preco"] . '</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                ';
                        }                        
                        //resultado final
                        echo '<td>Total R$:';
                        echo $total_pedido_soma;
                        echo '<center><button class="btn btn-success" rel="5" onclick="submete();">Comprar</button></center>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</table>';                          
                        echo '<form id="envia" method="POST" action="envia.php">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="total" value="'; print $codigo_loja; echo '" />'; 
                        echo'</form>';
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

É só concatenar o valor da variável com a string do botão 'hidden' que está sendo utilizado, uma vez concatenado na string, não importa se você altera ou não o valor da variável em outro loop.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="total" value="'.$codigo_loja.'" />';
```

Para concatenar o valor da variável na string com PHP basta utilizar '.', para saber mais sobre concatenação de string: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php

Comment: não resolveu o problema ainda...

Answer (score 0):

Cara pelo que eu entendi o seu problema é que você não consegue usar a variavel fora do while e isso é obvio se ela foi criada dentro do while ela só vai funcionar la, o que você precisa fazer é criar a variavel fora do while secundario, caso queira usar fora dos dois whiles então cria a variavel como null fora dos dois, a logica é a seguinte:
variavel=null
ao percorrer o while ela vai receber o valor e vai sair de la com o valor, e você vai poder usaa-la fora, seria algo assim

```
<?php
while (10 < 14){
    $variavel1 = null;
    while (10 < 14){
        $variavel1 = $x['id'];
    }
   echo $variavel1;
}
```

é obvio que você tem q adequar ao seus codigo, mas a logica é essa